# How to set wallpaper as tile?

Tags: android, android-wallpaper

I know in android how to set some wallpaper using the below code

```
    WallpaperManager wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(context);
```

Problem: I have a pattern tile small image, now I want to set this image as wallpaper as tiles. How to do that?